# How to delete and object from and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Thanks for your help in advance. I have been trying for two days how to delete an object which is stored in an array and I dont get it. Just reading a lot on forums and trying, but nothing works.

```
<head>

    <style>
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Global Array to saved more than one object without having to declare all of them
        var car = {};
        var i;
        var numRecords2 = 0;
        var doors;
        var outOfDateInsurance;
        var contRecords = -1;

        // Class Cars
        function Cars(record, brand, color, doors, insurance, outOfDateInsurance)
        {
            this.record = record;
            this.brand = brand;
            this.color = color;
            this.doors = doors;
            this.insurance = insurance;
            this.outOfDateInsurance = outOfDateInsurance;
        }

        //To validate number of the doors. It has to be 3 or 5
        function validateDoors()
        {
            doors = prompt("Number of doors");
            doors = parseInt(doors);

            if (isNaN(doors) === false && (doors == 3 || doors == 5))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Wrong character. Please, set 3 or 5");
                validateDoors();
            }
        }

        //To validate date's format 
        function validateFormatDate(outOfDateInsurance)
        {
            var RegExPattern = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}$/;
            if ((outOfDateInsurance.match(RegExPattern)) && (outOfDateInsurance!=''))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        //To check if the date is in the calendar
        function realDate(outOfDateInsurance)
        {
            var fechaf = outOfDateInsurance.split("/");
            var d = fechaf[0];
            var m = fechaf[1];
            var y = fechaf[2];
            return m > 0 && m < 13 && y > 0 && y < 32768 && d > 0 && d <= (new Date(y, m, 0)).getDate();
        }

        //To validate the date is over today
        function validateAboveDate(outOfDateInsurance)
        {
            var datef = outOfDateInsurance.split("/");
            var d = datef[0];
            var m = datef[1];
            var y = datef[2];

            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            if(dd<10)
            {
                dd='0'+dd
            } 
            if(mm<10)
            {
                mm='0'+mm
            } 
            var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
            var todayf = today.split("/");
            var dt = todayf[0];
            var mt = todayf[1];
            var yt = todayf[2];

            if ((d > dt) && (m >= mt) && (y >= yt))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((d = dt) && (m > mt) && (y >= yt))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((d < dt) && (m > mt) && (y >= yt))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //To validate the date's is right
        function checkingDate()
        {
            outOfDateInsurance = prompt("Insurance's End date (dd/mm/yyyy)");
            if(validateFormatDate(outOfDateInsurance))
            {
                if(realDate(outOfDateInsurance))
                {
                    if (validateAboveDate(outOfDateInsurance))
                    {
                        alert("Record has been introduced into the system");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("You have introduced an incorrect Insurance's End date");
                        checkingDate();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("You have introduced an incorrect Insurance's End date");
                    checkingDate();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("You have introduced an incorrect Insurance's End date");
                checkingDate();
            }
        }

        //To create objects
        function addCar()
        {
            var numRecords = prompt("How many records do you want to introduce to the system?");
            numRecords = parseInt(numRecords);

            if (isNaN(numRecords) === false)
            {
                var istart = contRecords + 1;
                var iend = numRecords2 + numRecords;

                //problema añadiendo cars porque reemplaza si no lo hago todo de una vez
                for (i = istart; i < iend; i++)
                {
                    contRecords++;
                    var record = contRecords;
                    var brand = prompt("Car's Brand");
                    var color = prompt("Car's Color");
                    validateDoors();
                    var insurance = confirm("Does have the car insurance? Press OK for YES and CANCEL for NO");
                    if (insurance === true)
                    {
                        insurance = "Yes";
                        checkingDate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        insurance = "No";
                        alert("Record has been introduced into the system");
                    }

                    //CONSTRUCTOR We are creating the object car in the Class Cars
                    car[i] = new Cars(record, brand, color, doors, insurance, outOfDateInsurance);
                }
                numRecords2 = numRecords2 + numRecords;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Please, introduce the number of the records you want to introduce");
                addCar();
            }
        }

        //To display the objects created
        function displayCar()
        {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "";
            for (i = 0; i < numRecords2; i++)
            {
                //we are creating an element <p>
                var parag = document.createElement('p');
                parag.id = "paragraph" + i;
                //we are creating an element <br>
                var br = document.createElement('br');
                //we are creating a text node
                var textRecord = document.createTextNode("Record: " + car[i].record);
                var textBrand = document.createTextNode("Brand: " + car[i].brand);
                var textColor = document.createTextNode("Color: " + car[i].color);
                var textDoors = document.createTextNode("Number of doors: " + car[i].doors);
                var textInsurance = document.createTextNode("Insurance: " + car[i].insurance);
                if (car[i].insurance === "Yes")
                {
                    var textOutOfDateInsurance = document.createTextNode("Date Insurance: " + car[i].outOfDateInsurance);
                }
                else
                {
                    var textOutOfDateInsurance = document.createTextNode("Date Insurance: ");
                }

                //we are adding the text nodes created to the <p>
                parag.appendChild(textRecord);
                //We are creating a clone from a node to have multiple break lines
                parag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
                parag.appendChild(textBrand);
                parag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
                parag.appendChild(textColor);
                parag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
                parag.appendChild(textDoors);
                parag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
                parag.appendChild(textInsurance);
                parag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
                parag.appendChild(textOutOfDateInsurance);
                //we are adding the whole <p> with the text nodes into the div created in the html
                document.getElementById("container").appendChild(parag);
            }
        }

        function deleteCar()
        {
            car[0] = null;
            car.splice(0);
            for (i = 0; i <= contRecords; i++)
            {
                alert(car[i]);
            }
            //if (contRecords >=0)
            //{
            //    var numRecordToDelete = prompt("Introduce the record's number you want to delete");
            //    numRecordToDelete = parseInt(numRecordToDelete);
            //    if (isNaN(numRecordToDelete) === false)
            //    {
            //        //var i = numRecordToDelete;
            //        //
            //        //    alert('Record: ' + i);
            //        //if(car[i].record === 'Record: ' + i)
            //        //{
            //        //    alert('Record: ' + i);
            //        //    car.splice(i,1);
            //        //    return false;
            //        //}
            //        car.shift();
            //        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = car;
            //    }
            //    else
            //    {
            //        alert("The character you have introduce is not a number");
            //        deleteCar();
            //    }
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    alert("There are no any record to delete");
            //    return;
            //}
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1 style="text-align: center;">WELLCOME TO THE AMAZING SOFTWARE TO ADD CARS TO YOUR SYSTEM</h1>
    <br><br>

    <!-- Button to create the object car -->
    <input type="button" value="Add Car" onclick="addCar()">
    <!-- Button to display the objects created -->
    <input type="button" value="See Cars" onclick="displayCar()">
    <input type="button" value="Delete Cars" onclick="deleteCar()">
    <BR>
    <hr>
    <BR>
    <!-- Div which information's objects is going to be displayed -->
    <div id="container"></div>

</body>
```

So the thing is, I am adding objects to the array like a BBDD and i dont know how to do it to delete one object from the array and re-organize the other objects in the array's positions like, if I delete the element's array number 2, then, the number 3 will be the second one and the fodth one would be the third, etc...

Thanks a lot, any doubt, please, let me know. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: please include only a stripped-down version of your code. Only a few lines that demonstrates your problem

Comment: for javascript its .splice().

Comment: `car.splice(0,1);` should do the trick

Comment: Hi Guys! I am sorry I had to add all my code but I didnt know how to show my problem just with a few lines... I am kind of new working with javascript...

Vicky Gonsalves, I had used splice before and I dont know why it is not working........ Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//Global Array to saved more than one object without having to declare all of them
var car = [],
    doors,
    outOfDateInsurance;


// Class Cars
function Cars(record, brand, color, doors, insurance, outOfDateInsurance)
{
  this.record = record;
  this.brand = brand;
  this.color = color;
  this.doors = doors;
  this.insurance = insurance;
  this.outOfDateInsurance = outOfDateInsurance;
}

//To validate number of the doors. It has to be 3 or 5
function validateDoors()
{
  doors = prompt("Number of doors");
  doors = parseInt(doors);

  if (isNaN(doors) === false && (doors == 3 || doors == 5))
  {
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Wrong character. Please, set 3 or 5");
    validateDoors();
  }
}

//To validate date's format 
function validateFormatDate(outOfDateInsurance)
{
  var RegExPattern = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}$/;
  if ((outOfDateInsurance.match(RegExPattern)) && (outOfDateInsurance!=''))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

//To check if the date is in the calendar
function realDate(outOfDateInsurance)
{
  var fechaf = outOfDateInsurance.split("/");
  var d = fechaf[0];
  var m = fechaf[1];
  var y = fechaf[2];
  return m > 0 && m < 13 && y > 0 && y < 32768 && d > 0 && d <= (new Date(y, m, 0)).getDate();
}

//To validate the date is over today
function validateAboveDate(outOfDateInsurance)
{
  var datef = outOfDateInsurance.split("/");
  var d = datef[0];
  var m = datef[1];
  var y = datef[2];

  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if(dd<10)
  {
    dd='0'+dd
  } 
  if(mm<10)
  {
    mm='0'+mm
  } 
  var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
  var todayf = today.split("/");
  var dt = todayf[0];
  var mt = todayf[1];
  var yt = todayf[2];

  if ((d > dt) && (m >= mt) && (y >= yt))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    if ((d = dt) && (m > mt) && (y >= yt))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      if ((d < dt) && (m > mt) && (y >= yt))
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}

//To validate the date's is right
function checkingDate()
{
  outOfDateInsurance = prompt("Insurance's End date (dd/mm/yyyy)");
  if(validateFormatDate(outOfDateInsurance))
  {
    if(realDate(outOfDateInsurance))
    {
      if (validateAboveDate(outOfDateInsurance))
      {
        alert("Record has been introduced into the system");
      }
      else
      {
        alert("You have introduced an incorrect Insurance's End date");
        checkingDate();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      alert("You have introduced an incorrect Insurance's End date");
      checkingDate();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    alert("You have introduced an incorrect Insurance's End date");
    checkingDate();
  }
}

//To create objects
function addCar()
{
  var numRecords = prompt("How many records do you want to introduce to the system?");
  numRecords = parseInt(numRecords);

  if (isNaN(numRecords) === false)
  {
    var iend = numRecords;

    //problema añadiendo cars porque reemplaza si no lo hago todo de una vez
    for (var i = 0; i < iend; i++)
    {
      var brand = prompt("Car's Brand");
      var color = prompt("Car's Color");
      validateDoors();
      var insurance = confirm("Does have the car insurance? Press OK for YES and CANCEL for NO");
      if (insurance === true)
      {
        insurance = "Yes";
        checkingDate();
      }
      else
      {
        insurance = "No";
        alert("Record has been introduced into the system");
      }

      //CONSTRUCTOR We are creating the ARRAY car in the Class Cars
      car.push(new Cars(car.length + 1, brand, color, doors, insurance, outOfDateInsurance));
    }
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Please, introduce the number of the records you want to introduce");
    addCar();
  }
  displayCar();
}

//To display the objects created
function displayCar()
{
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < car.length; i++)
  {
    //we are creating an element <p>
    var parag = document.createElement('p');
    parag.id = "paragraph" + i;
    //we are creating an element <br>
    var br = document.createElement('br');
    //we are creating a text node
    var textRecord = document.createTextNode("Record: " + car[i].record);
    var textBrand = document.createTextNode("Brand: " + car[i].brand);
    var textColor = document.createTextNode("Color: " + car[i].color);
    var textDoors = document.createTextNode("Number of doors: " + car[i].doors);
    var textInsurance = document.createTextNode("Insurance: " + car[i].insurance);
    if (car[i].insurance === "Yes")
    {
      var textOutOfDateInsurance = document.createTextNode("Date Insurance: " + car[i].outOfDateInsurance);
    }
    else
    {
      var textOutOfDateInsurance = document.createTextNode("Date Insurance: ");
    }

    //we are adding the text nodes created to the <p>
    parag.appendChild(textRecord);
    //We are creating a clone from a node to have multiple break lines
    parag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    parag.appendChild(textBrand);
    parag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    parag.appendChild(textColor);
    parag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    parag.appendChild(textDoors);
    parag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    parag.appendChild(textInsurance);
    parag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    parag.appendChild(textOutOfDateInsurance);
    //we are adding the whole <p> with the text nodes into the div created in the html
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(parag);
  }
}

function deleteCar()
{
  if (car.length >0)
  {
    var numRecordToDelete = prompt("Introduce the record's number you want to delete");
    numRecordToDelete = parseInt(numRecordToDelete);
    if (isNaN(numRecordToDelete) === false)
    {
      alert('Record: ' + numRecordToDelete);
      if(numRecordToDelete >= car.length)
      {
        alert('Record: ' + numRecordToDelete);
        car.splice(numRecordToDelete - 1,1);
        displayCar();
        return false;
      }
      else {
        alert("Record not exist");
        deleteCar();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      alert("The character you have introduce is not a number");
      deleteCar();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    alert("There are no any record to delete");
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">WELCOME TO THE AMAZING SOFTWARE TO ADD CARS TO YOUR SYSTEM</h1>
<br><br>

<!-- Button to create the object car -->
<input type="button" value="Add Car" onclick="addCar()">
<!-- Button to display the objects created -->
<input type="button" value="See Cars" onclick="displayCar()">
<input type="button" value="Delete Cars" onclick="deleteCar()">
<BR>
<hr>
<BR>
<!-- Div which information's objects is going to be displayed -->
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your explanation. Take care!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.splice() to delete entries from an array.
[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
car.splice(0,1);
```

Comment: I don't understand. `splice` does **not** return the result, and it **does** affect the original array.

Comment: Yep, my bad. Editted to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I should you work with an array of objects. Actually you work with an object how array where re many objects. With this is more easy foreach actual cars to add, see and delete.

```
car = [];
```

when add:

```
car.push(new Cars(record, brand, color, doors, insurance, outOfDateInsurance));
```

Other than that, I suggest you when you add or delete car, refresh data for the client can see changes and refreshing records number for deletes.

When your splice a element of array, the other elements after will move -1. For this reason must call displayCar() at the end.

```
var numRecordToDelete = prompt("Introduce the record's number you want to delete");
car.splice(numRecordToDelete,1);
```

Comment: Joaquin, thanks a lot! Your idea works perfectly! I am kind of new on JS, just learning it because of work. I am guessing I can talk to you on spanish. Could you explain me again what I have done with your idea in spanish please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Claro, te lo pongo como otra respuesta porque en los comentarios está bastante limitado.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand what you are looking for and the example provided should address that, if not let me know.

```
  <script>
  var collectionOfObjects = [];
  collectionOfObjects.push({name: "anObject1"});
  collectionOfObjects.push({name: "anObject2"});
  collectionOfObjects.push({name: "anObject3"});
  collectionOfObjects.push({name: "anObject4"});

  console.log("collectionOfObjects initial state");
  console.log(collectionOfObjects);
  console.log("deleteing 2nd member - this will delete the object even if other things have reference to it and not just remove it from the collection");
  console.log("deleteing 2nd member - it will croupt the length of the array but we can fix that");
  delete collectionOfObjects[2];
  collectionOfObjects = collectionOfObjects.sort();
  collectionOfObjects.length = collectionOfObjects.length - 1
  console.log("collectionOfObjects after delete");
  </script>
```

On a side note I just noticed you could do this also:

```
  //To validate date's format 
  function validateFormatDate(outOfDateInsurance)
  {
      var RegExPattern = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}$/;
      return outOfDateInsurance.match(RegExPattern) && (outOfDateInsurance!='')
  }
```